# What is the mistake in my derivation of the wrong asymptotic relation $n^n = O(n!)$?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Since $n^n = e^{n\log(n)}$, the Taylor series of $e^n$ gives $$ n^n = 1+n\log(n)+O(n^2 \log^2(n)). $$

And $n\log(n) \in O(n!)$ and $ O(n^2 \log^2(n)) \subset O(n!)$, so $n^n = O(n!)$, which is ridiculous.

Could you please point out any mistakes in my calculation? Thank you in advance. Any comment or answer is appreciated.

Comment: You have written $$n^n = 1+n\log(n)+O(n^2 \log^2(n)).$$
Is the last part really $O(n^2 \log^2n)$?

Comment: Sorry I honestly do not know. What is the mistake here? I subed $n^2\log^2n$ into $e^n = 1+n+O(n^2).$

Comment: What would be the next term in the Taylor expansion, and is it really smaller than your $O$-term? Note that you are considering $n \to \infty$, not $n \to 0$.

Comment: Oh! It seems that this expansion works only when $n\to 0$?

Comment: Well yes and no, the Taylor series converges everywhere, but if you truncate it, things go awry for large $n$ since you're cutting off higher order terms---those terms are *big* if $n$ is big, and they're *small* if $n$ is small.

Comment: I see... So how many terms should I have? How do you determine the order to which the terms you use? @prets

Comment: For $n$ large, each term is bigger than the last, so you have to include all of them. If you truncate anywhere, you face the exact same problem.

Comment: Thank you! I got the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x$ large, the terms in the Taylor series
$$ e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \dots $$
grow larger and larger, so truncating the series will give a wildly wrong estimate (and it will get more wrong the larger $x$ gets).